# CakePHP using Email component from Shell cronjob

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm trying to send an email from a CakePHP shell just as you would from the Controller.

Most of the code below was adapted from [this dated article on the Bakery](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Jippi/2007/12/02/emailcomponent-in-a-cake-shell) and it's comments. The email is sending, however the line `$controller->set('result', $results[$i]);` throws the following notices:

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   View::$webroot in
>   /home/jmccreary/www/intranet.sazerac.com/cakephp/cake/libs/view/view.php
>   on line 813
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: result in
>   /home/jmccreary/www/intranet.sazerac.com/cakephp/app/views/elements/email/text/nea/task_reminder_it.ctp
>   on line 2

So I'm not getting any of the variables passed to my email view.

How can I do this, ideally following the Cake conventions?

```
class NotificationShell extends Shell {
    var $uses = array('Employee', 'Task');

    function main() {
        // run if no action is passed
    }

    function nea_task_reminder() {
        // build Task to Employee relationship
        $this->Task->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Employee' => array('className' => 'Employee', 'foreignKey' => 'object_id'))));
        $results = $this->Task->find('all', array('conditions' => array('application_id' => 1, 'completed_by_id' => 0), 'contain' => array('Employee' => array('Contact', 'Position'))));

        $count = count($results);
        if ($count) {
            App::import('Core', 'Controller');
            App::import('Component', 'Email');
            $controller =& new Controller();
            $email =& new EmailComponent();
            $email->startup($controller);

            // send email
            $email->from = Configure::read('Email.from');
            $email->to = 'jmccreary@whatever.com';
            $email->replyTo = 'no-reply@whatever.com';
            $email->template = 'nea/task_reminder_it';
            $email->sendAs = 'text';

            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
                $email->subject = 'NEA Notification: Task Reminder for ' . $results[$i]['Employee']['Contact']['full_name'];
                $controller->set('result', $results[$i]);
                $email->send();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is the way you're initializing the `EmailComponent` class. If you look at the source code, the `startup()` method doesn't actually have a body so it does nothing. Your controller isn't actually assigned to the `EmailComponent`. The problem isn't `$controller->set('results', ...);`. You need to use `EmailComponent::initialize()` instead of `EmailComponent::startup()`.

```
$controller =& new Controller();
$email =& new EmailComponent(null);
$email->initialize($controller);
```

**Sources:**

1. Comments section of http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Jippi/2007/12/02/emailcomponent-in-a-cake-shell
2. [EmailComponent::startup() Source](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/email-component/#line-345)

Comment: I suppose I should have just kept reading the Bakery article. Time to go earn +50 back.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using CakePHP 2.x, you can ditch the `EmailComponent` entirely and use the [`CakeEmail` class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) instead.

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class NotificationShell extends Shell {
    public function send() {
        $email = new CakeEmail();
    }
}
```

That entirely avoids all the thorny issues of loading components inside a shell.  For email at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CakePHP 2.x, try to use `CakeEmail` instead.

`CakeEmail#viewVars()` provides setting variables to template.

Here is example using CakeEmail from Shell.
https://gist.github.com/tsmsogn/cee9cef2e851e7684021

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
App::import('Core', 'Controller');
App::import('Component', 'Email');
$this->Controller =& new Controller();
$this->Email =& new EmailComponent(null);
$this->Email->initialize($this->Controller);    

//use set function as below  
$this->controller->set('result', $results[$i]);
```

for more reference click on below link:

http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/cron_shell_-_mail

Comment: Thanks, but this is the same code I have. It's just *cleaner* with the `$this` prefix.