# How to load a component in console/shell

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP, how do I load a component in a shell?

To use a component in a controller, you include an array of components in a property called $components. That doesn't work for my Shell. Neither does the "on-the-fly" loading suggested in the documentation.

```
class MakePdfsShell extends Shell {
    public $components = array('Document'); // <- this doesn't work
    public function main()
    {
        $this->Document = $this->Components->load('Document'); // <- this doesnt work either
        $this->Document->generate(); // <- this is what I want to do
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to access a custom XyzComponent from a shell, then you probably have commonly-useful functionality there. The right place for commonly-useful functionality (that is also accessible from shells) is in `/Lib/`.

You can just move your old XyzComponent class from `/Controller/Component/XyzComponent.php` to `/Lib/Xyz/Xyz.php`. (You should rename your class to remove the "Component" suffix, e.g., "XyzComponent" becomes "Xyz".)

To access the new location, in your controller, remove 'Xyz' from your `class::$components` array. At the top of your controller file, add

```
App::uses('Xyz', 'Xyz'); // that's ('ClassName', 'folder_under_/Lib/')
```

Now you just need to instantiate the class. In your method you can do `$this->Xyz = new Xyz();` Now you're using the same code, but it can also be accessed from your Shell.

Comment: Top suggestion. My thoughts exactly on semantics. I had common functionality to share between a shell task and a controller, this method keeps things DRY.

Comment: Is the syntax the same (`App::uses()`) inside the shell class? I'm on CakePHP v3.x

Comment: This, in it self, without extra advice/precautions, is a bad practice. You should note to carefully check for code usage/interlinking with other components (and any previous "uses" declarations), remove the code from a class all together if the only cause for it being in an XYZ class was only the architecture of CakePHP and even then it's recommended to load such sections with require/require_once. We had a case of in-house "copy the component code to lib" and lost some needless debugging time.

Comment: I think we should avoid to user  `$this->xyz = new XyZ();` and inject the dependency, typehintent by an interface... so your services are changable

Answer (score 12):

I have some xml utilities that I use across some of my controllers. One of the controller launches a heavy task via the cake console, so that it can quietly run in the background via PHP CLI, while the user's request is immediately completed (once the task done, it will e-mail the results to the user).

The xml utilities are generic enough to be used in controller and shell, are too specific to the application to warrant them vendor status. The offered solution with the Lib folder does not work as in `CakePhp v3` there seems to be no `Lib` folder.

After some quite some time spent, I managed to load my controller component to the shell task. Here is how to:

```
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;

use Cake\Core\App;
use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
use App\Controller\Component\XmlUtilitiesComponent;   // <- resides in your app's src/Controller/Component folder

class XmlCheckShell extends Shell
{

    public function initialize() {
        $this->Utilities = new XmlUtilitiesComponent(new ComponentRegistry());
    }

...
```

`$this->Utilities` can now be used across my entire shell class.

Comment: I am a little concerned that a Component may not be the right place for this kind of integration but +1 as it works for me too.

Comment: I don't understand why this is upvoted. Probably by people who don't know or care about good architecture. Using components outside the scope of a controller and request can and *very likely will* lead to unexpected behavior of the code. This can have *very* strange side effects depending on what the component does and depends on. Also why does XML manipulation stuff have to go into a component? This is simply the wrong place. This should go into a genuine class placed in App\Utility\XmlUtils for example and have *no* dependencies to the request nor controller. Downvoted for that reason.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details that address the issues with this answer here as well.

Answer (score 8):

#### You simply don't.

If you think you have to load a component in shell your application architecture is bad designed and should be refactored.

Technically it is possible but it doesn't make sense and can have pretty nasty side effects. Components are not made to run outside of the scope of a request. A component is thought to run within the scope of a HTTP request and a controller - which is obviously not present in a shell.

#### Putting things in the right place

Why does XML manipulation stuff have to go into a component? This is simply the wrong place. This should go into a class, maybe `App\Utility\XmlUtils` for example and have **no** dependencies at all to the request nor controller.

The logic is properly decoupled then and can be used in other places that need it. Also if you get incoming XML the right place to do this manipulation (by using your utility class) would be inside the model layer, not the controller.

#### You want to learn about Separation of Concerns and tight coupling

Because you've gone just against both principles.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns
- [What is the difference between loose coupling and tight coupling in the object oriented paradigm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832017/what-is-the-difference-between-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling-in-object-orien)

#### Search before asking

You could have tried to search [via Google](https://www.google.de/webhp?q=cakephp+shell+component) or [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cakephp%20shell%20component) you would have found one of these:

- [using components in Cakephp 2+ Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140149/using-components-in-cakephp-2-shell)
- [CakePHP using Email component from Shell cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411954/cakephp-using-email-component-from-shell-cronjob)
- [Using a plugin component from shell class in cakephp 2.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880694/using-a-plugin-component-from-shell-class-in-cakephp-2-0-2)
- ...

Be aware that some of them might encourage bad practice. I haven't checked them all.

Comment: -1. Solid answer, but you sound like a jerk. Being polite and sounding helpful as you present your answer is just as important on this type of site as is being right. Not everyone is as smart or experienced as you.

Comment: @burzum why do you have to be so condescending?

Comment: @schnauss I don't think I'm condescending. Direct, but not condescending. If you like to discuss this further talk to me on IRC or Slack. ctlockey brilliant, down voting the correct answer while the other one gives false advice because of ad hominem...

Comment: where to put the "services" with DI Configuration when not into components? When i hear about Utility ... my heart cries loud... i think if we have classes named XyzUtility.... in our Application, then we have implemented classes we really dont know what they exists for.

Comment: @SimonMüller it's an example, I have no clue what he wants to do. Processing XML data should be clearly separated from the controller and data passed to the object. Why would you need a controller to process XML inside the XML processing class? So a "service" *requires* a controller for you? Thats how it sounds. I strongly disagree with that. You're free to put whatever class in whatever namespace in Cake. Just create App\Service\FooService and do whatever you want in FooService, even `new FooServce(Controller $foo)` if you *really* want to do that...

Comment: but how then do i create DI Services to use in Shell Commands with Cake PHP? I want to fetch data from an api and store it to a mysql database, where can i put this logic (the api client/the parser etc.) when not in components?

Comment: Pretty easy? The only dependency such a class would have is probably a HTTP client object. So either pass it to it or construct it inside. Then instantiate that API client in your shell, model objects or controller. And what is a "DI service" for you? DI is a *very* broad topic, usually people want a DI container when talking about DI in Cake. IMHO most people use a DI container like a super global for everything and create spaghetti code any way.

Comment: Gotta agree both to ctlockey and burzum. Burzum didn't have to sound like a jerk, but he also shouldn't get a negative tho it's a complete (even more) answer.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that you have a component named **YourComponent**:

```
<?php

App::uses('Component', 'Controller');

class YourComponent extends Component {

    public function testMe() {
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

### - **with cake 2.**, you can load your component like this

```
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('YourComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class YourShell extends AppShell {

    public function startup() {
        $collection = new ComponentCollection();
        $this->yourComponent = $collection->load('Your');
    }

    public function main() {
        $this->yourComponent->testMe();
    }
}
```

### - **with cake 3.** you can load your component like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Shell;


use App\Controller\Component\YourComponent;
use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;

class YourShell extends Shell {

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->yourComponent = new YourComponent(new ComponentRegistry(), []);
    }

    public function main() {
        $pages = $this->yourComponent->testMe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exact answer, I need... Thanks

Comment: +1, even though burzum's answer is in theory correct it doesn't contain the information I needed this answer does. While I agree with @burzum that it's most likely a sign of bad design decisions, one does not always have the possibility, the time or even the freedom to make it right - think of an app that is going to be dead soon anyway. Is a major refactoring worth it in such case? I don't think so.

Answer (score -3):

//TestShell.php

```
class TestShell extends AppShell{

    public function test(){
        //to load a component in dis function
     App::import('Component', 'CsvImporter');
     $CsvImporter = new CsvImporterComponent();
     $data = $CsvImporter->get();
    }

}
```

//CsvImporterComponent.php

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');

class CsvImporterComponent extends Component {

    function get(){
    //your code
    }

}
```

Comment: That is not how you do it, ever. See the correct answer "You simply don't." below.