# CakePHP 3.x Using Controller Methods in Shell

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron

I am trying to do background email sending in my application.

I am making a shell that I will eventually schedule to be run through a crontask.

I am trying to run the following code in my EmailShell:

```
<?php
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Core\App;

App::import('Controller', 'Messages');

class EmailShell extends Shell{
    public function main(){
        //Check for unsent emails
        $messagesCont = new MessagesController;
        $messages = $messagesCont->findAllUnsent();

        //Send all unsent emails
        foreach ($messages as $message){
        $email = new Email();

        $email->to($messages->receiver)
            ->subject($message->subject)
            ->send($message->body);
        }
      //Update the table to be marked as sent
    }   
}
?>
```

The code that I need from the MessagesController is as such:

```
 public function findAllUnsent(){
     $messages = $this->paginate($this->Messages);

    foreach ($messages as $message){
      if ($message->sent == false){
        //If message is unsent then add it to the array
        $messagesFound[] = $message;
      }
    }
    //Return the array of unsent messages
    return $messagesFound;
  }
}
```

However when I run the shell through the command line terminal using `bin/cake email`

I get the following error:

> Exception: Call to undefined method Cake\Core\App::import() in
>   [/home/cabox/workspace/src/Shell/EmailShell.php, line 7]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511023/how-to-load-a-component-in-console-shell replace component with controller and the answer is exactly the same. Could be flagged as a duplicate of it.

Comment: @burzum So how else would you suggest doing emails in the background? There are no resources online whatsoever to do this and I am struggling to find a detailed and up to date guide for CakePHP 3.x

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [**the answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28511076/1392379) to the question linked in the comments, you shouldn't use a controller in your shell at all. That code should be in your model, for example in a finder, or just a regular class method.

It should also be noted that the use of the paginator contradicts the method name, which says "find all", the paginator however will by default find only a maximum of 20 records. Also I'd suggest to filter the records on SQL level instead, so that you only receive those records that you actually need, reducing them afterwards will break the pagination, as it operates with the numbers calculated for the original result.

So in your `MessagesTable` class add for example a custom finder like:

```
public function findUnsent(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->where([
        $this->aliasField('sent') => false
    ]);
}
```

And in your shell use the model, like:

```
class EmailShell extends Shell
{
    use Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait;

    public function main()
    {
        // tableLocator() before CakePHP 3.5
        $MessagesTable = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Messages');
        $unsentMessages = $MessagesTable->find('unsent');

        foreach ($unsentMessages as $message) {
            // ...
        }
    }   
}
```

Similarily you'd use the finder then in your controller too, and pass a query to the `paginate()` method instead.

btw, there is no `App::import()` anymore, CakePHP 3.x uses [**Composer**](https://getcomposer.org) autoloading now, that call there should trigger an error.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.ORM.Locator.LocatorAwareTrait.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Pagination > Using Controller::paginate()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate)**